# Getting sandboxed with ajax and jquery mobile

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

I need to pull some code from a desktop site to a mobile site but I am running into some errors
Here is the error that I am getting

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://brunswickchurch.org/youth. Origin http://w5webdesigns.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Here is the code

```
$.ajax({
          url: "http://brunswickchurch.org/youth",
          crossDomain: true,
          success: function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                var content = $("#content-area", data )[0]; /// returns the 0th element of an array with 1 element
                //console.log(content);
              $(content).find('img').remove();
              $(content).find('hr').remove();
              $("#doane").html(content); // get that 1 element (the entire content-area div) and replace the doane div's content on this page
         }
      });
```

Here is the call in the HTML

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
        <div id="doane">kjgflguif
        <p>listen to the current sermon</p>
        </div>       
    </div>
```

I had this working on a mac with safari but I cannot seem to get it working on my windows or android for that matter, is there a better way. A more cross browser compatible way to pull this off?